# How would you go about finding the natural frequencies (resonance frequency)

Tags: experimental-physics, frequency

How would you go about finding the natural frequencies of solid materials like wood (e.g., teak, pine), stone (e.g., marble, granite) liquid, etc?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense as it is.  What do Pa and dB have to do with the natural frequency of an object?  Can you add an example of an object whose resonant frequencies you would like to know?

Comment: Thank you to begin with as you can see am not the brightest just interested which to me is the start, I was thinking like stone, water, wood etc maybe marble and teak does that help

Comment: How would you go about finding natural frequencys I guess that's.my real question

Comment: There is no natural frequency for materials.  There are natural frequencies for objects, which have vibrational modes with frequencies.  Please think about what you are trying to ask.

Comment: No your on the right line, now can i ask why there's no natural frequency in material what happens if we vibrate the atoms of these materials would that not cause a frequency? And would that frequency not be the natural frequency of that material

Comment: you need to clarify your question, whether you mean the natural frequency of vibration or the electromagnetic frequencies,etc. and size and shape of the material also matters, constraints, etc. you need to formulate a precise example.

Comment: The resonance frequency of an object would be the one it makes when you hit it. The natural frequency of  the vibration and rotation of molecules is what you see in a IR spectrum. What are you referring to?

Comment: You seem to be confusing two very different things here. The behavior of atoms can be explained in terms of resonances which occur on *very* short time scales (attoseconds--microseconds) dominated by the size of the the atom, the speed of light and quantum processes. The vibrational behavior a macroscopic pieces of material occurs on time scales short by human reckoning but still very much longer than that for atomic processes (milliseconds to seconds) characterized by the size of the object and the speed of sound in that material. "Natural frequency" generally refers to the latter.