# resonance frequency of a cylinder fixed on a wall from one side

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, resonance

[image]How can we calculate the resonance   frequency for a cylinder fixed horizontally  to a wall from one side ? it  is  not  bar  or  cantilever

Comment: I'm under the impression that, typically, one *experimentally* determines the resonant frequency.

Comment: This appears to be essentially a duplicate of [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102283/) that was closed as "unclear."

Comment: @KyleKanos: no, using the inertial moment of the cylinder and elastic modulus we can set up an equation of motion for harmonic oscillation and find the natural frequency of the object.

Comment: To be clearer the question could do with simple situation diagram.

Comment: Can you also explain why it's *not a cantilever*? And if it's not a bar, do you mean a hollow cylinder?

Comment: Hi;  I  think  we can  suppose  it is  cylindrical cantilever which should  be  has  different  calculation  or  hollow  cylinder  that what  I  meant